# Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So I'm getting this error:
Argument of type '{ "username:": string; "password": string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type  'string'

My code:

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  responseData : any;
  userData = {"username:":"", "password":""};

  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private authloginService: AuthloginService, public navCtrl : NavController ) {   
  }

  fazerLogin(){

     this.authloginService.logarConta(this.userData, 'login').then((result)=>{ // error here
      this.responseData = result;
      console.log(this.responseData);
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('home')

     });
```

EDIT1: AuthloginService with the function logarConta:

```
export class AuthloginService {



  private API_URL: 'https://myapi.com/api';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  logarConta(email: string, password:string){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      var data = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        message: 'Test',

      };

      this.http.post(this.API_URL + 'login', data)
        .subscribe((result: any) =>{
          resolve(result.json())
        }, 
        (message) =>{
          reject(message.json())
        })
    });
```

Comment: Hello, could you share with us the definition of your AuthloginService.logarConta function?

Comment: first argument of `authLoginService.logarConta()` is a string not an object

Comment: @JohnGraham just eddited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
this.authloginService.logarConta(this.userData.username, this.userData.password)
.then((result)=>{
  this.responseData = result;
  console.log(this.responseData);
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward('home')
 });
```

But, Im not sure if this `logarConta` method is good. Because you have there a `email` argument, and your `userData = {"username:":"", "password":""};` has not email key. You should check if this is correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

Awesome thanks for sharing.  The problem is that you have an object `userData` which has 2 string properties username and password.  Your logarConta function is expecting 2 string variables email and password, but you are just passing 1 object.  You can fix this by changing your call to look like this:

```
  this.authloginService.logarConta(this.userData.username, this.userdata.password).then((result)=>{ // error here
  this.responseData = result;
  console.log(this.responseData);
  this.navCtrl.navigateForward('home')

 });
```

This will properly map the properties of the object to the variables the function is expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score -1):

```
this.authloginService.logarConta(...this.userData, 'login')
```